# Flask redirect to page then come back

Tags: python, flask

I have a small flask app that I want to, when a link is clicked, go to that link then return back to the page you just left.

The reason is the link goes to a physical devices reboot page. I have many of these devices and want to have the script run through them, reboot then return to the start page.

I can get to the link and the unit resets but it has no way of coming back, as it is now on an external page. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Thanks to @xyres I have the following:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request
import urllib

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/reboot')
def reboot():
    link = request.args.get('link')
    if link:
        urllib.request.urlopen(link)
    return redirect(request.referrer or url_for('index'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

but it hits the page and doesnt wait long enough before redirecting so the unit doesnt reboot...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the request to the external links from your backend. Instead of giving the actual link to the client, give them an alternate link that you control. For example:

```
http://yourapp.com/make-request?link=http://actual-link.com
```

So, you create a handler at `/make-request/` url for this.

```
from flask import request, redirect, url_for
import urllib

@app.route('/make-request')
def make_request()
    link = request.args.get('link')
    if link:
        urllib.urlopen(link) # for Python 3.x use urllib.request.urlopen

    # now redirect back to the referrer
    # if no referrer, redirect to some_view
    return redirect(request.referrer or url_for('some_view'))
```

Comment: Just so I am clear, you want me to put the link i want to go to, not the word 'link' after urlopen?

Comment: @cmrussell You're right. That was a typo. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Once the browser goes to another page, the server that redirected the browser more or less loses control of the browser. Think about it: Would you want to go to a webpage on the Internet that can continue to control your browser even after you left that page?

One alternative you might consider, however, is using an iframe instead of a traditional link. Here's an example of a web page that loads Wikipedia in an iframe when you click a button, then closes it when you click that you're done.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#btn-go').click(function() {
        $('#ifr-loader').show();
        $('#ifr-loader').attr('src', 'https://www.wikipedia.org');
    });
    $('#btn-finish').click(function() {
        $('#ifr-loader').attr('src', '');
        $('#ifr-loader').hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn-go">Go to Other Site</button>
<button id="btn-finish">Finish</button>

<hr>
<iframe id="ifr-loader" style="display: none; width: 100%; height: 80%"></iframe>
```

Comment: I realize that once it hits the other page I no longer have control. It only needs to go there long enough to allow the unit to reboot (I have about 125 of them).